# Webform and Membership

Tags: webform-civicrm

I recently switched from a normal Civicrm contribution page to a Webform one. Since then, the relationship between contribution and membership is not so clear.

The new Members do appear in the membership list but individually the membership is considered to be null like on this image:

[image]

If I look inside each new members' profile, I can see they paid a contribution for a membership ('cotisation' in French)

[image]

but in the membership tab, I see no membership and the status is still on "Waiting for a payment"

[image]

It only changes if I enter manually a payment. The strange thing is that if I look at the Membership dashboard, these members do appear on the dashboard page:

[image]

but if I look deeply in the number of "real members" then they don't show up:

[image]

This is how looks the membership part in the webform-civicrm tab. 'Adhésion annuelle' is the Membership type and 'cotisation' means membership.

[image: membership configuration]

and the contribution one. The contribution page is the one that was previously used and that worked fine. (I only have one). There is a contribution amount but it's new and the situation was the same already before.

[image]

Has anyone already encountered this situation?

I'm running an up-to-date Drupal 7 / Civicrm with webform-civicrm.

EDIT 1 ::
I've created a new webform to test with live payment and I'm getting to the same situation.

EDIT 2 :: if I have a look at Drupal logs and focus on webform-civicrm, I can see at least twice this error at the time I have the new memberships.

```
The CiviCRM "contribution sendconfirmation" API returned the error: "field description unset or not existing" when called by function "postSave" on line 248 of wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc with parameters: "Array ( [id] => 195 [title] => Adhésion et renouvellement d'adhésion au SNPMNS [intro_text] =>

    Dans le cadre d'une primo adhésion ou d'un renouvellement via ce formulaire en ligne, nous vous demandons de le remplir de la manière la plus exhaustive possible afin de simplifier et d'améliorer l'établissement de votre assurance RC professionnelle.

    IMPORTANT : Si vous changez d'adresse en cours d'année, envoyez-nous vos nouvelles coordonnées rapidement
    Tous les champs avec un * sont obligatoires
    [financial_type_id] => 2 [is_credit_card_only] => 0 [is_monetary] => 1 [is_recur] => 0 [is_confirm_enabled] => 1 [is_recur_interval] => 0 [is_recur_installments] => 0 [adjust_recur_start_date] => 0 [is_pay_later] => 1 [pay_later_text] => Je paierai par chèque ou par virement électronique [pay_later_receipt] =>

    Merci de nous adresser sous 3 jours votre chèque ou votre virement pour le paiement de la cotisation au SNPMNS.

    Vous recevrez ensuite votre kit adhérent comprenant l'attestation d'assurance RC prestataire de services.

    Notre compte en banque pour le virement :

    IBAN : FR76 1820 6001 6316 3910 0900 159

    Notre adresse pour nous adresser le chèque :

    80, boulevard du Général LECLERC
    BP 3 - 92113 Clichy la Garenne CEDEX
    [is_partial_payment] => 0 [is_allow_other_amount] => 0 [thankyou_title] => Bienvenue au SNPMNS [thankyou_text] =>

    Nous vous remercions pour votre adhésion au SNPMNS et notre équipe se rapprochera de vous dans les plus brefs délais.


    [thankyou_footer] =>

    Merci de ne pas répondre à ce message automatique.
    [is_email_receipt] => 1 [receipt_from_name] => SNPMNS service adhésion [receipt_from_email] => adhesion@snpmns.org [cc_receipt] => adhesion@snpmns.org [bcc_receipt] => contact@all-in-appli.com [receipt_text] => Nous vous remercions pour votre adhésion au SNPMNS et notre équipe se rapprochera de vous dans les plus brefs délais. La période de validité de l'adhésion inscrite dans ce courriel de confirmation est donnée à titre indicatif seulement et votre adhésion ne sera réellement effective qu'après le contrôle par l'équipe en charge des adhésions et la transmission des éventuels documents administratifs indispensables à l'établissement de l'attestation d'assurance RC-pro. Dans l'attente de vous rencontrer lors de nos actions. L'équipe du SNPMNS [is_active] => 1 [amount_block_is_active] => 0 [start_date] => 2019-04-24 13:56:00 [created_date] => 2019-04-24 13:58:12 [currency] => EUR [is_share] => 0 [is_billing_required] => 1 [contribution_type_id] => 2 [payment_processor_id] => 1 [check_permissions] => [version] => 3 ) "
```

EDIT 3 :: I need to manually override status in the individual contact tab to make the membership active

[image]

EDIT 4 :: I don't need anymore to apply EDIT 3 because of the patches in CiviCRM 5.19 that correct the translation of "Pending". Still I need to "save" a payment to make it be recorded. Is this related to MembershipsStatus?

[image: Membershipsstatus]

Comment: "Has anyone already encountered this situation?" - nope and we have set up many many sites with webforms doing the membership + contribution

Comment: ok! at least what happens is not usual. I have to dig further into this issue.

Comment: I compared "old" and "new" contribution, and I can see that there is no change for the "membership status". I don't know where to look :(

Comment: you could add screenshots of your webform-civi tab esp the Cont. and the Memb vertical tabs, and the webform components screen

Comment: done, with other screenshots from the members dashboard that shows that the new member are "half" registered.

Comment: still not seeing what is amiss. very odd.

Comment: :-(. I'm stuck. I'm having a look at logs.

Comment: I found some errors within Drupal logs, but I don't know how to interpret these

Comment: is it only a problem for certain Payment Processor?

Comment: I have only 2 options: online payment with Stripe (that works fine as a Membership Contribution) or Pay later with bank transfer or check. In this second situation, you need to enter manually the payment. It's the core process from 'Contribution' to 'Membership' that fails. Should I reinstall webform-civicrm?

Comment: have you confirmed that purchasing a Membership directly via the Contribution page is working?

Comment: yes. this is the normal page we used to use and membership contributions were automatically turned into memberships : https://gestad.net/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1. I hoped trying with a new contribution test page and a new test webform would help me to learn something but actually it didn't :(

Comment: I found to way to manually make this change for each new member (override stratus) but this is really not the way I want to use CiviCRM...

Comment: would like to help you get over this problem, esp. if you are volunteering for a good project

Comment: what kind of good project? ;)

Comment: could this be related to MembershipStatus or Cron Job "update membership"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by setting everything back like it is out of the box when you install CiviCRM.

**RULE #1: don't play with Membershipstatus rules**

This is what I learnt after struggling for months.

If you have access to PhpmyAdmin, this is how it should be set:

[image]