# webform civicrm error

Tags: webform-civicrm

I am still [troubleshooting Webform](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31711/webform-and-membership?noredirect=1#comment36211_31711) and looking at the logs while testing a membership I saw this Error message which might - or not - be related to my initial problem:

```
The CiviCRM "contribution sendconfirmation" API returned the error: "field description unset or not existing" when called by function "postSave" on line 248 of wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc with parameters: "Array ( [id] => 228 [title] => Adhésion et renouvellement d'adhésion au SNPMNS [intro_text] =>

    Dans le cadre d'une primo adhésion ou d'un renouvellement via ce formulaire en ligne, nous vous demandons de le remplir de la manière la plus exhaustive possible afin de simplifier et d'améliorer l'établissement de votre assurance RC professionnelle.

    IMPORTANT : Si vous changez d'adresse en cours d'année, envoyez-nous vos nouvelles coordonnées rapidement
    Tous les champs avec un * sont obligatoires
    [financial_type_id] => 2 [is_credit_card_only] => 0 [is_monetary] => 1 [is_recur] => 0 [is_confirm_enabled] => 0 [is_recur_interval] => 0 [is_recur_installments] => 0 [adjust_recur_start_date] => 0 [is_pay_later] => 1 [pay_later_text] => Je paierai par chèque ou par virement électronique [pay_later_receipt] =>

    Merci de nous adresser sous 3 jours votre chèque ou votre virement pour le paiement de la cotisation au SNPMNS.

    Vous recevrez ensuite votre kit adhérent comprenant l'attestation d'assurance RC prestataire de services.

    Notre compte en banque pour le virement :

    IBAN : FR76 1820 6001 6316 3910 0900 159

    Notre adresse pour nous adresser le chèque :

    80, boulevard du Général LECLERC
    BP 3 - 92113 Clichy la Garenne CEDEX
    [is_partial_payment] => 0 [is_allow_other_amount] => 0 [thankyou_title] => Bienvenue au SNPMNS [thankyou_text] =>

    Nous vous remercions pour votre adhésion au SNPMNS et notre équipe se rapprochera de vous dans les plus brefs délais.


    [thankyou_footer] =>

    Merci de ne pas répondre à ce message automatique.
    [is_email_receipt] => 1 [receipt_from_name] => SNPMNS service adhésion [receipt_from_email] => adhesion@snpmns.org [cc_receipt] => adhesion@snpmns.org [bcc_receipt] => contact@all-in-appli.com [receipt_text] => Nous vous remercions pour votre adhésion au SNPMNS et notre équipe se rapprochera de vous dans les plus brefs délais. La période de validité de l'adhésion inscrite dans ce courriel de confirmation est donnée à titre indicatif seulement et votre adhésion ne sera réellement effective qu'après le contrôle par l'équipe en charge des adhésions et la transmission des éventuels documents administratifs indispensables à l'établissement de l'attestation d'assurance RC-pro. Dans l'attente de vous rencontrer lors de nos actions. L'équipe du SNPMNS [is_active] => 1 [amount_block_is_active] => 0 [start_date] => 2019-04-24 13:56:00 [created_date] => 2019-04-24 13:58:12 [currency] => EUR [is_share] => 0 [is_billing_required] => 1 [contribution_type_id] => 2 [payment_processor_id] => 0 [check_permissions] => [version] => 3 ) "
```

How could I improve that issue making a membership contribution not becoming a membership?

EDIT::

Following Jitendra's advice, disabling receipt on the contribution page helped. Now I have two last warnings that appeared for each new membership:

```
Warning : implode(): Invalid arguments passed dans CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::postProcess() (ligne 1481 dans /home/allingro/gestad/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php).

Warning : array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given dans CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::postProcess() (ligne 1479 dans /home/allingro/gestad/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php).
```

This is the related code in this file:

```
// added for CheckBox
      case 'CheckBox':
        if (!empty($v)) {
          $customValue = array_keys($v);
          $groupTree[$groupID]['fields'][$fieldId]['customValue']['data'] = CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR
            . implode(CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR, $customValue)
            . CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR;
        }
```

Comment: Don't think resolving the above error will fix the membership issue you have in your previous post. But you can try disabling the "Receipt" option from the contribution page setting and check.

Comment: Try creating a new membership instead of renewing an existing one. It should make sure that the error is only occurring for renewals or also replicate for new memberships.

Comment: thanks jitendra, I will do some tests this way