# Defining Membershipstatus Rules and update issue

Tags: civimember

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/defining-memberships/) about membershipstatus rules and something stays unclear. Even with a contribution, the Pending status stays and is not being updating (see my related post: [webform and membership](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31711/webform-and-membership?noredirect=1#comment36211_31711))

**Should I set the beginning of "New" at "Member since" or "Start date"?**

The journey I defined is:

[image]

Any ideas to help?

best regards,
Guillaume

Comment: I know that membership statuses based on payments are quite a pain in the ass. My experience is that I leave the statuses as it is and only change the duriation of the new, expired and grace stauses.

Comment: I believe that the membership has pending as long as the contribution has the status pending. As soon as the contributions gets the status completed the membership will get the status new/active.

Comment: that's exactly the core of my issue. The contribution has status "completed" but the membership stays under "Pending" status. Which means I have to open each individual membership on the next day and just save. Then it updates the status of the membership. At least, I feel more safe to read from you that that "membership statuses based on payments are quite a pain in the ass". I am really spending a lot of time to make this work automatically. I am really dreaming of fixing this issue :-(

Comment: There is also a cron job which updates the membership statuses

Comment: we have seen people who have tweaked their Status but have failed to realise they must be totally continuous, ie when one ends the next one starts. i don't suspect that is your issue but flagging as a warning.

Comment: guillaume - can you pm me - peter.davis@fuzion.co.nz

Comment: I tweaked and I failed. Solution found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved with [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/33815/6991): **NEVER MODIFY MEMBERSHIPSTATUS RULES!** except if your really know what you're doing.